# 日本語に違和感: 投稿を編集中に右に表示されるヘルプ: 編集方法

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

> 編集方法
>   ► 文法または文字の間違いを直す
>   ► 意味を変えないで、もっとわかりやすく説明する
>   ► ささいな間違いを修正する
>   ► 関連するリソースまたはリンクを追加する
>   ► _常に_元の投稿者に敬意を払う

- 「編集方法」: 方法というよりガイドラインかチェックリストに近い
- 「元の投稿者に敬意を払う」: 意図を尊重、とした方がヘルプの意図が伝わりやすい

原文

```
How to Edit
► fix grammatical or spelling errors
► clarify meaning without changing it
► correct minor mistakes
► add related resources or links
► always respect the original author
```

Comment: `_文字_`のMarkupが日本語で使えない為、それを`*文字*`に変えるべきです。

Answer (score 2):

> 編集チェックリスト
>   ✓ 誤字脱字や「てにをは」を修正
>   ✓ 元の意味を残しつつ、よりわかりやすく
>   ✓ その他の些細な間違いをなおす
>   ✓ 参考になる文献やリンクを追加する
>   ✓ 投稿者の意図を**常に**尊重すること

斜体はあまり和文で見かけないため、強調部分は太字にしました。

Answer (score 1):

entoさんの案を一部組み入れ、全体の文体を統一しました。現在、これらの文字列は通常の翻訳フローでの翻訳作業を受け入れています。随時改良が可能です。

「How to Edit」を「編集チェックリスト」とする案は採用していません。翻訳文字列が別の文脈で使用される可能性の有無を確認できていないからです。

現在の翻訳:

> 編集方法
>
> - 些細なタイプミスや間違いを修正する
> - 意味を変えずに明確にする
> - 関連するリソースやリンクを追加する
> - 投稿者の意図を**常に**尊重する
> - 編集を使って作成者に返信しない

現在の原文:

> How to Edit
>
> - Correct minor typos or mistakes
> - Clarify meaning without changing it
> - Add related resources or links
> - *Always* respect the author’s intent
> - Don’t use edits to reply to the author